# 1 Code Base, multiple domains, How to create sitemap files

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I have created a site, that uses 1 code base, but multiple domains access that codebase. 
Now the content served-up shows different CSS and imagery.

My question i'm running into, is, how do I generate a Sitemap file for each domain. 
I have looked at using, http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/  and using their Script, but that will only work for 1 domain.

Other than creating my own code to do the site scraping, I don't see any other route. Do you know of another solution instead of having to start from scratch? Ideally would love to hit the ground running.

Note: The script needs to crawl the site. Thoughts?

Comment: surely you're using a framework that lets you generate a sitemap. If not, then yeah, you wrote the code that serves all the routes you came up with, so just make your code generate it. Unless your code doesn't even know which routes it's servicing in which case you coded yourself into a hole... recursive wget last resort.

Comment: So what's the problem to generate XML sitemap for every domain? Or you've a lot of them and it's really hard to create XML sitemap for every domain?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and Oleg The problem comes as the site is 'dynamic', if I knew I had only 50 pages, it would be easy to do, but because a lot of the pages are dynamically produced, it causes a problem. IE: www.Domain.com/search-for-juice    or, www.Domain.com/search-for-jobs   And yeah I do have a number of these sites so it creates some difficulties....

Comment: the example URLs you gave should never be in a sitemap. sitemaps are for static content and entry points to dynamic content.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hmm, really? Is that documented somewhere? My understanding, was based on all content.

Comment: [you use a sitemap for a poorly linked website](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en) to mitigate the problem of crawling not working. Linking to constantly-dynamic content pages like search page is the kind of things you do as an SEO spammer: the page you added to the sitemap is not real content. Generating a sitemap for dynamic-but-static-once-made, like blog content, on the other hand makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ahh, I never saw that online, thank you. Do not want the "spam" label. If you want to provide an "answer" I can send the rep. your way.

Comment: hm, it's really an answer to the original question though, I'm okay with simply having helped understand sitemaps a little more and not getting the rep =)

Comment: As a sidenote: link your pages among themselves. This will allow you to use any crawler to create an XML sitemap.

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion?  If not, it is a very important technique for even beginning programmers to understand.  PHP has directory crawlers built in, but if you don't want to use those you can really write a simple recursive script in a matter of minutes.  If you need help let me know and I'd be happy to lend some code! :)

Comment: @JS Yeah I understand recursion a bit. Not the best at it in a sense. I don't want to recurse a directory. But I might be able to do it on a DB layer.

Comment: If you still need a hand, let me know and I'll be happy to show you a simple recursive solution that will only require a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Mutliple sitemaps for single codebase something challanging job but not the impossible one. I am supposing that you are using some kind of framework for working of website.

Theer are many problem which comes during creating such thing are:

1. How to identify which request is coming from which website. So, the problem is to create the sitemap for specific site for the request is recieved.
2. Somehow, if you identify the which request is coming from which website then your website is dynamic. How to record these paramenters.
3. Where to store the such a huge database. Somehow if you resolve these things the mutlitple sites requests/parameters which database would be large enough to store such large requests.
4. If you somehow manage the huge database then next problem about submitting such a huge xml to search engine.
5. Sitemap would start growing daily the time for creation would certainly go up and so the request of crawling from website would also grow daily.
6. If your sitemap grows huge and same pages are submitted for different website then content would be marked as spam along with website.

There are some problems which can be unseen or predicted and thus it will be risky thing. Now to do it.

## solutions

For problem 1st and 2nd we have to use the PHP `$_SERVER` - which provides the information about Server and execution environment information, such as parameters, hostname, requested host and many other things.

Now for problem 3 to 6, we have use the text files to store the requests one file for one domain and provide request details. The file must be flushed after particular time i.e. daily, weekly etc.

While creating sitemap we have to read the file and get the unqiue parameters, so that the sitemap doesn't include multiple same urls.

**warning**: It is highly recommended that don't do such thing as it will trigger the spamming and would be identified soon and marked as spammers websites.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions built into this answer:

1. The URI elements trailing the domain name are the same on each domain, for all pages.

   `i.e. http://site-one.com/page/1` is the same as `http://site-two.com/page/1`
2. You are able to manipulate the file provided by xml-sitemaps. This is a concern if you need to generate this on a continuous basis, meaning you would need to create a script to do the following per href.

If you don't mind using the service you mentioned at http://www.xml-sitemaps.com and , then by far the easiest way to do this would be to use that service and then change all absolute URLs to relative URLs. You can write any link that looks like

```
http://www.example.com/category/page
```

as a relative link at

```
/category/page
```

In short, that starting slash is the key, indicating to the browser to 'use the current domain'. You can do a find and replace on all all instances of `http://www.example.com/`, converting to `/` + the remaining string of URI elements.

Comment: If you need to generate the Site Map programatically, you can't avoid crawling... but to easily traverse the DOM of a crawled page, you can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get all href values in an array.

Comment: Yeah that's not a bad idea actually. Could build a script on the "results" and have it automatically make the adjustments...Although most likely not a "clean" solution...

Comment: Definitely not "clean" since your dependent on a third-party without an API, but if you're not updating often this is a very quick solution